# An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine

Tags: java

I am trying to process an excel file.but i am encountering following problem

```
An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:

SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x68efbaf4, pid=15849, tid=4149892800

 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (1.5.0_22-b03 mixed mode)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [libclntsh.so.10.1+0x1beaf4]  kpuhhalpuc+0x43a

 An error report file with more information is saved as hs_err_pid15849.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:


   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp


/opt/Migration/run.sh: line 9: 15849 Aborted                 $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Djava.library.path=/opt/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_3/lib32 -classpath $CLSPTH -Xmx2048M packagename.classname
```

can anybody help me.

Comment: Are you also involving a database? It seems to be Oracle database-related.

Comment: might be irrelevant but what is the size of your excel file ??

Comment: @Marko,                                                             Yes,We are processing the excel file and based on each record validation the relevant data will be inserted into oracle database tables.

Comment: @Hussain, The size of the excel file is around 5.4M and it contains around 36000 records.

Comment: So let me tell you how I knew it was Oracle-related: I googled for `libclntsh.so.10.1` and for `kpuhhalpuc`. Try finding out more that way.

Comment: @Marko,Yes i am in that process.

Comment: If the Excel file was too big, we'd get an `OutOfMemoryError`. It's a bug in VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means the Java runtime has a severe bug (it tried to access memory of other processes) and your application has somehow triggered it.

The next step is to see which shared libraries you have added to the process. Maybe there are newer versions.

If you use Oracle, use the pure Java thin client instead of OCI.

Maybe you have found a real bug in your version of Java. Try to upgrade to the latest version. If that doesn't help, file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issue. I was able to fix it. HotSpot Virtual Machine tries to access memory of other processes. Make sure you use same JVM for build compile and also your eclipse is using the same JVM as you build tool.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem, but resolved by following below steps:

1. Right click on project, select build path
2. Remove java jre library
3. again add the default java library
4. clean and publish the server