# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment [GCTaskThread ]

Tags: java, jvm, java-6

How can I solve this problem and prevent it from happening, this error shutdown my JVM process and the tomcat went down I noted that the current thread is GCTaskThread, I think it is JVM bug but I am not sure

```
  #
    # An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006d80fefc, pid=15232, tid=6900
    #
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0-b15 mixed mode windows-amd64)
    # Problematic frame:
    # V  [jvm.dll+0xefefc]
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
    #

    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x000000000602f400):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000] [id=6900]

    siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000010

    Registers:
    EAX=0x00000000d89719a3, EBX=0x000000000049e0a0, ECX=0x0000000000000000, EDX=0x00000002f8a19b90
    ESP=0x000000000d5dfb40, EBP=0x000000000d5dfcf0, ESI=0x00000000000019b6, EDI=0x000000000049e0a4
    EIP=0x000000006d80fefc, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

    Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000d5dfb40)
    0x000000000d5dfb40:   000000000049e0a0 000000000d5dfcf0
    0x000000000d5dfb50:   00000000000019b6 000000000049e0a4
    0x000000000d5dfb60:   00000000d89619a3 00000000d89719a3
    0x000000000d5dfb70:   00000000d89619a3 0000000000000000
    0x000000000d5dfb80:   000000006db8f348 00000000060dec80
    0x000000000d5dfb90:   000000000602ebe0 000000020cc20000
    0x000000000d5dfba0:   000000002f400000 0000000332220000
    0x000000000d5dfbb0:   0000000000020000 000000000602ed40
    0x000000000d5dfbc0:   000000000049e0a0 000000000602ee80
    0x000000000d5dfbd0:   000000000602efa0 000000033230e040
    0x000000000d5dfbe0:   000000000dbdfb70 000000000d5dfcf0
    0x000000000d5dfbf0:   0000000000000001 0000000000000001
    0x000000000d5dfc00:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x000000000d5dfc10:   0000000332220000 0000000000020000
    0x000000000d5dfc20:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x000000000d5dfc30:   000000020cc20000 000000000092b801 

    Instructions: (pc=0x000000006d80fefc)
    0x000000006d80feec:   60 fe ff ff 49 8b 4d 08 4c 8d 44 24 40 49 8b d5
    0x000000006d80fefc:   48 8b 41 10 48 83 c1 10 ff 90 c0 01 00 00 44 8b 


    Stack: [0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000],  sp=0x000000000d5dfb40,  free space=219006k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    V  [jvm.dll+0xefefc]


    ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

    Java Threads: ( => current thread )
      0x0000000012995c00 JavaThread "Lucene Merge Thread #0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15968, stack(0x0000000000d10000,0x0000000000d90000)]
      0x0000000010905800 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-1796" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=17268, stack(0x0000000024c70000,0x0000000024cf0000)]
      0x0000000010903c00 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-1795" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1892, stack(0x0000000024bf0000,0x0000000024c70000)]
      0x0000000010906c00 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-1794" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=17432, stack(0x0000000024990000,0x0000000024a10000)]
      0x000000001200e400 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-1793" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16504, stack(0x0000000024510000,0x0000000024590000)]
      0x000000001200dc00 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-1792" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15684, stack(0x0000000016dc0000,0x0000000016e40000)]
      0x000000001200f000 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-1791" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18360, stack(0x0000000016c10000,0x0000000016c90000)]
      0x0000000012998400 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-1790" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=17568, stack(0x00000000169c0000,0x0000000016a40000)]
      0x0000000012997000 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-1789" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9644, stack(0x00000000167c0000,0x0000000016840000)]
      0x0000000012996800 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-1788" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13624, stack(0x0000000011500000,0x0000000011580000)]
      0x0000000012996000 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-exec-1787" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7176, stack(0x0000000000b90000,0x0000000000c10000)]
      0x0000000012860800 JavaThread "File Reaper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15000, stack(0x00000000266c0000,0x0000000026740000)]
      0x0000000012a2f400 JavaThread "pool-5-thread-15" [_thread_in_Java, id=16760, stack(0x0000000015e20000,0x0000000015ea0000)]
      0x000000001285ec00 JavaThread "pool-5-thread-14" [_thread_blocked, id=8360, stack(0x00000000251f0000,0x0000000025270000)]
      0x0000000012864000 JavaThread "pool-5-thread-13" [_thread_blocked, id=16500, stack(0x0000000024610000,0x0000000024690000)]
      0x0000000012997c00 JavaThread "pool-5-thread-12" [_thread_in_native, id=10528, stack(0x0000000024590000,0x0000000024610000)]
      0x0000000012865000 JavaThread "pool-5-thread-11" [_thread_in_native, id=16404, stack(0x0000000013a20000,0x0000000013aa0000)]
      0x000000001ac5a000 JavaThread "File Reaper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16944, stack(0x0000000026740000,0x00000000267c0000)]
      0x0000000012997800 JavaThread "File Reaper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14112, stack(0x0000000016e60000,0x0000000016ee0000)]
      0x0000000012a30000 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-11" [_thread_blocked, id=15480, stack(0x0000000016640000,0x00000000166c0000)]
      0x0000000012a2ec00 JavaThread "RMI RenewClean-[10.224.0.128:49437]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13388, stack(0x0000000024cf0000,0x0000000024d70000)]
      0x0000000010a19800 JavaThread "pool-4-thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=15768, stack(0x0000000027320000,0x00000000273a0000)]
      0x000000001ac5a800 JavaThread "pool-9-thread-10" [_thread_blocked, id=12564, stack(0x0000000026ed0000,0x0000000026f50000)]
      0x0000000010a18400 JavaThread "pool-4-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=13116, stack(0x0000000026e50000,0x0000000026ed0000)]
      0x0000000010a17c00 JavaThread "pool-4-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=4524, stack(0x0000000026dd0000,0x0000000026e50000)]
      0x0000000010a17400 JavaThread "pool-4-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=16252, stack(0x0000000026d50000,0x0000000026dd0000)]
      0x000000001ac5d800 JavaThread "http-nio-4080-exec-10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12084, stack(0x0000000026cd0000,0x0000000026d50000)]
      0x0000000012518800 JavaThread "http-nio-4080-exec-9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15144, stack(0x0000000026c50000,0x0000000026cd0000)]
      0x0000000012863800 JavaThread "http-nio-4080-exec-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10508, stack(0x0000000026a80000,0x0000000026b00000)]
      0x000000001182b800 JavaThread "http-nio-4080-exec-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15084, stack(0x0000000024810000,0x0000000024890000)]
      0x00000000107ac000 JavaThread "pool-9-thread-9" [_thread_blocked, id=15832, stack(0x0000000024790000,0x0000000024810000)]
      0x00000000107a8000 JavaThread "pool-9-thread-8" [_thread_blocked, id=5232, stack(0x00000000256a0000,0x0000000025720000)]
      0x0000000012010c00 JavaThread "pool-4-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=9024, stack(0x0000000025500000,0x0000000025580000)]
      0x00000000203bcc00 JavaThread "http-nio-4080-exec-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14552, stack(0x00000000253a0000,0x0000000025420000)]
      0x000000000fe9b800 JavaThread "http-nio-4080-exec-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15292, stack(0x0000000024a90000,0x0000000024b10000)]
      0x000000000fe98000 JavaThread "http-nio-4080-exec-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14276, stack(0x0000000024910000,0x0000000024990000)]
      0x000000000fe98800 JavaThread "http-nio-4080-exec-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15048, stack(0x0000000024710000,0x0000000024790000)]
      0x00000000127bec00 JavaThread "http-nio-4080-exec-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15464, stack(0x0000000024200000,0x0000000024280000)]
      0x00000000127bc800 JavaThread "http-nio-4080-exec-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9988, stack(0x0000000024280000,0x0000000024300000)]
      0x00000000127c0800 JavaThread "pool-9-thread-7" [_thread_blocked, id=15512, stack(0x0000000024690000,0x0000000024710000)]
      0x00000000127c0c00 JavaThread "pool-9-thread-6" [_thread_blocked, id=14696, stack(0x0000000016a40000,0x0000000016ac0000)]
      0x000000001ac5d400 JavaThread "pool-9-thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=15308, stack(0x0000000022d80000,0x0000000022e00000)]
      0x000000001ac5b800 JavaThread "pool-9-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=4208, stack(0x0000000024a10000,0x0000000024a90000)]
      0x0000000012010800 JavaThread "pool-9-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=2924, stack(0x0000000026bd0000,0x0000000026c50000)]
      0x000000001200f800 JavaThread "pool-9-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=15164, stack(0x0000000026b50000,0x0000000026bd0000)]
      0x0000000012517400 JavaThread "pool-9-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=2516, stack(0x0000000025480000,0x0000000025500000)]
      0x000000001ac5cc00 JavaThread "SaveLoginThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14772, stack(0x0000000024890000,0x0000000024910000)]
      0x00000000127bd400 JavaThread "org.python.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15448, stack(0x0000000024b70000,0x0000000024bf0000)]
      0x00000000127bc000 JavaThread "EMDRPendingAcknowledgmentsThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15040, stack(0x0000000024300000,0x0000000024380000)]
      0x00000000127bf000 JavaThread "Abandoned connection cleanup thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14576, stack(0x0000000024100000,0x0000000024180000)]
      0x00000000127c1400 JavaThread "pool-7-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=5668, stack(0x0000000023e80000,0x0000000023f00000)]
      0x00000000127c1c00 JavaThread "PerformanceThresholdThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6608, stack(0x0000000022e00000,0x0000000022e80000)]
      0x00000000107a8800 JavaThread "Timer-30" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15504, stack(0x0000000016cc0000,0x0000000016d40000)]
      0x0000000012865400 JavaThread "pool-5-thread-10" [_thread_in_native, id=4512, stack(0x00000000164c0000,0x0000000016540000)]
      0x0000000012865c00 JavaThread "pool-5-thread-9" [_thread_blocked, id=8252, stack(0x00000000161c0000,0x0000000016240000)]
      0x0000000012861c00 JavaThread "pool-5-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=11308, stack(0x0000000000c90000,0x0000000000d10000)]
      0x00000000203bec00 JavaThread "pool-5-thread-3" [_thread_in_native, id=14388, stack(0x0000000000c10000,0x0000000000c90000)]
      0x00000000203bb800 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-10" [_thread_blocked, id=12580, stack(0x0000000024490000,0x0000000024510000)]
      0x00000000203bb000 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-9" [_thread_blocked, id=10132, stack(0x0000000024410000,0x0000000024490000)]
      0x000000001182b000 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-8" [_thread_blocked, id=12340, stack(0x0000000024390000,0x0000000024410000)]
      0x000000001182a400 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-7" [_thread_blocked, id=15716, stack(0x0000000024080000,0x0000000024100000)]
      0x0000000011829c00 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-6" [_thread_blocked, id=13088, stack(0x0000000024000000,0x0000000024080000)]
      0x0000000011829400 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=6268, stack(0x0000000024180000,0x0000000024200000)]
      0x0000000011828000 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=15864, stack(0x0000000023f80000,0x0000000024000000)]
      0x0000000011828c00 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=14588, stack(0x0000000023f00000,0x0000000023f80000)]
      0x000000001285f400 JavaThread "pool-6-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=14036, stack(0x0000000016d40000,0x0000000016dc0000)]
      0x0000000012863400 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=828, stack(0x0000000025720000,0x00000000257a0000)]
      0x000000001285e400 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7420, stack(0x0000000025620000,0x00000000256a0000)]
      0x000000000fe99400 JavaThread "pool-5-thread-1" [_thread_in_Java, id=15300, stack(0x0000000016040000,0x00000000160c0000)]
      0x00000000107aac00 JavaThread "SaveLoginThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6596, stack(0x0000000016f40000,0x0000000016fc0000)]
      0x00000000127bb800 JavaThread "Timer-16" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=15428, stack(0x0000000011480000,0x0000000011500000)]
      0x00000000107a7400 JavaThread "org.python.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16012, stack(0x0000000016940000,0x00000000169c0000)]
      0x00000000107a6c00 JavaThread "EMDRPendingAcknowledgmentsThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14840, stack(0x00000000168c0000,0x0000000016940000)]
      0x00000000107a6400 JavaThread "Abandoned connection cleanup thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15592, stack(0x0000000016840000,0x00000000168c0000)]
      0x00000000107a5c00 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=9636, stack(0x000000000ee00000,0x000000000ee80000)]
      0x000000000fe97400 JavaThread "PerformanceThresholdThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8468, stack(0x000000000ed80000,0x000000000ee00000)]
      0x00000000127c2400 JavaThread "Timer-15" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6140, stack(0x000000000ed00000,0x000000000ed80000)]
      0x00000000127bd000 JavaThread "Timer-10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13540, stack(0x0000000016540000,0x00000000165c0000)]
      0x00000000127bac00 JavaThread "org.python.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1140, stack(0x0000000016440000,0x00000000164c0000)]
      0x000000000fe9ec00 JavaThread "EMDRPendingAcknowledgmentsThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13508, stack(0x00000000163c0000,0x0000000016440000)]
      0x000000000fe9e400 JavaThread "Abandoned connection cleanup thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12720, stack(0x0000000016340000,0x00000000163c0000)]
      0x000000000fe9dc00 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=13384, stack(0x00000000162c0000,0x0000000016340000)]
      0x000000000fe9d400 JavaThread "PerformanceThresholdThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12372, stack(0x0000000016240000,0x00000000162c0000)]
      0x000000000fe9c800 JavaThread "RMI RenewClean-[10.224.0.128:52451]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15764, stack(0x0000000016140000,0x00000000161c0000)]
      0x000000000fe9c000 JavaThread "RMI Scheduler(0)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14868, stack(0x00000000160c0000,0x0000000016140000)]
      0x000000000fe9b000 JavaThread "RMI Reaper" [_thread_blocked, id=5360, stack(0x0000000015f20000,0x0000000015fa0000)]
      0x000000000fe9ac00 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-1099" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1976, stack(0x0000000015ea0000,0x0000000015f20000)]
      0x000000000fe9a400 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14260, stack(0x0000000015fc0000,0x0000000016040000)]
      0x000000000fe99000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11484, stack(0x0000000015da0000,0x0000000015e20000)]
      0x00000000110b2400 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7956, stack(0x0000000015d20000,0x0000000015da0000)]
      0x0000000010936000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Poller" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5556, stack(0x0000000015ca0000,0x0000000015d20000)]
      0x000000001253d800 JavaThread "http-nio-4080-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=13596, stack(0x0000000014be0000,0x0000000014c60000)]
      0x00000000125aa800 JavaThread "http-nio-4080-ClientPoller-1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14684, stack(0x0000000014b60000,0x0000000014be0000)]
      0x0000000010848000 JavaThread "http-nio-4080-ClientPoller-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=13896, stack(0x0000000014ae0000,0x0000000014b60000)]
      0x00000000100ff400 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4564, stack(0x00000000139a0000,0x0000000013a20000)]
      0x0000000010b37c00 JavaThread "http-bio-8443-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=11736, stack(0x0000000013920000,0x00000000139a0000)]
      0x00000000102de800 JavaThread "http-apr-80-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14488, stack(0x00000000138a0000,0x0000000013920000)]
      0x0000000014450400 JavaThread "http-apr-80-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14804, stack(0x0000000013820000,0x00000000138a0000)]
      0x0000000010abc000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-Sendfile" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13884, stack(0x00000000137a0000,0x0000000013820000)]
      0x000000000dabb000 JavaThread "http-apr-80-Poller" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13648, stack(0x0000000013720000,0x00000000137a0000)]
      0x000000001100ac00 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14784, stack(0x00000000136a0000,0x0000000013720000)]
      0x0000000015438400 JavaThread "Thread-5" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3872, stack(0x0000000013620000,0x00000000136a0000)]
      0x000000000ffa0400 JavaThread "Thread-4" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=12968, stack(0x00000000135a0000,0x0000000013620000)]
      0x0000000014913800 JavaThread "Thread-3" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14160, stack(0x0000000013520000,0x00000000135a0000)]
      0x00000000100fa000 JavaThread "NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=15912, stack(0x0000000011400000,0x0000000011480000)]
      0x000000001095e400 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4532, stack(0x000000000f7c0000,0x000000000f840000)]
      0x000000000d7f6000 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=13364, stack(0x000000000f740000,0x000000000f7c0000)]
      0x000000000d9a0c00 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-8484" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=14464, stack(0x000000000f6c0000,0x000000000f740000)]
      0x000000000fc38000 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=15168, stack(0x000000000f280000,0x000000000f300000)]
      0x000000000d817c00 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16140, stack(0x000000000f200000,0x000000000f280000)]
      0x000000000d814400 JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14860, stack(0x000000000f100000,0x000000000f200000)]
      0x000000000d80b800 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15612, stack(0x000000000f000000,0x000000000f100000)]
      0x000000000d809c00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15600, stack(0x000000000ef80000,0x000000000f000000)]
      0x000000000d809800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8108, stack(0x000000000ef00000,0x000000000ef80000)]
      0x000000000d809000 JavaThread "Surrogate Locker Thread (CMS)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5996, stack(0x000000000ee80000,0x000000000ef00000)]
      0x000000000d7e6c00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15976, stack(0x000000000ebf0000,0x000000000ec70000)]
      0x000000000d7e1000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14624, stack(0x000000000eb70000,0x000000000ebf0000)]
      0x000000000059c800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=15492, stack(0x0000000000f90000,0x0000000001090000)]

    Other Threads:
      0x000000000d7dcc00 VMThread [stack: 0x000000000ea70000,0x000000000eb70000] [id=12896]
      0x000000000d7f6800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000000f860000,0x000000000f960000] [id=13984]

    =>0x000000000602f400 (exited) GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000] [id=6900]

    VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

    VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

    Heap
     par new generation   total 3019200K, used 708576K [0x0000000140020000, 0x000000020cc20000, 0x000000020cc20000)
      eden space 2683776K,  23% used [0x0000000140020000, 0x000000016685e158, 0x00000001e3d00000)
      from space 335424K,  23% used [0x00000001f8490000, 0x00000001fd04a280, 0x000000020cc20000)
      to   space 335424K,   0% used [0x00000001e3d00000, 0x00000001e3d00000, 0x00000001f8490000)
     concurrent mark-sweep generation total 5144576K, used 4627981K [0x000000020cc20000, 0x0000000346c20000, 0x0000000346c20000)
     concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 508816K, used 305061K [0x0000000346c20000, 0x0000000365d04000, 0x0000000386c20000)

    Dynamic libraries:
    0x0000000140000000 - 0x000000014001e000     d:\Tomcat7\bin\Tomcat7.exe
    0x0000000077520000 - 0x00000000776c9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
    0x0000000077300000 - 0x0000000077420000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
    0x000007fefd2e0000 - 0x000007fefd34c000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
    0x000007fefd900000 - 0x000007fefd9db000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
    0x000007fefdda0000 - 0x000007fefde3f000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
    0x000007fefdb50000 - 0x000007fefdb6f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
    0x000007fefdf10000 - 0x000007fefe03d000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
    0x000007fefe1a0000 - 0x000007fefef29000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
    0x000007feff5d0000 - 0x000007feff641000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
    0x000007fefd9e0000 - 0x000007fefda47000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
    0x0000000077420000 - 0x000000007751a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
    0x000007feff330000 - 0x000007feff33e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
    0x000007fefde40000 - 0x000007fefdf09000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
    0x000007feff300000 - 0x000007feff32e000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
    0x000007fefe090000 - 0x000007fefe199000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
    0x000000006d720000 - 0x000000006dcd8000     D:\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
    0x000007fef9220000 - 0x000007fef925b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
    0x000000006d350000 - 0x000000006d35a000     D:\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\bin\hpi.dll
    0x00000000776f0000 - 0x00000000776f7000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
    0x000000006d6e0000 - 0x000000006d6ee000     D:\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\bin\verify.dll
    0x000000006d3f0000 - 0x000000006d417000     D:\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\bin\java.dll
    0x000000006d700000 - 0x000000006d712000     D:\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\bin\zip.dll
    0x000007feff3c0000 - 0x000007feff5c3000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
    0x000007fefd120000 - 0x000007fefd12f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
    0x000007fefbb70000 - 0x000007fefbd64000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_fa3b1e3d17594757\comctl32.dll
    0x000007feff220000 - 0x000007feff2f7000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
    0x000007feff650000 - 0x000007feff827000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
    0x000007fefd530000 - 0x000007fefd566000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
    0x000007fefd4e0000 - 0x000007fefd4fa000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
    0x000000006d530000 - 0x000000006d53a000     D:\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\bin\management.dll
    0x000000006d5f0000 - 0x000000006d607000     D:\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\bin\net.dll
    0x000007fefe040000 - 0x000007fefe08d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
    0x000007fefd680000 - 0x000007fefd688000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
    0x000007fefca60000 - 0x000007fefcab5000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
    0x000007fefca50000 - 0x000007fefca57000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
    0x000007fefbdf0000 - 0x000007fefbe05000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
    0x000007fefa600000 - 0x000007fefa615000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
    0x000007fefc800000 - 0x000007fefc85b000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
    0x000007fefa350000 - 0x000007fefa35b000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
    0x000007fefc470000 - 0x000007fefc477000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
    0x000007fefba80000 - 0x000007fefbaa7000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
    0x000007fefb9e0000 - 0x000007fefb9eb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
    0x000007fef95a0000 - 0x000007fef95a8000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
    0x000007fefb6d0000 - 0x000007fefb723000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
    0x000007fefccb0000 - 0x000007fefccc8000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
    0x000007fefc770000 - 0x000007fefc7b7000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
    0x000007fefd2c0000 - 0x000007fefd2cf000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
    0x0000000011270000 - 0x00000000113fc000     D:\Tomcat7\bin\tcnative-1.dll
    0x000000006d610000 - 0x000000006d61b000     D:\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\bin\nio.dll
    0x000000006d680000 - 0x000000006d686000     D:\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\bin\rmi.dll
    0x0000000065340000 - 0x0000000065351000     D:\Tomcat7\temp\jffi2021.tmp
    0x0000000069340000 - 0x00000000693c5000     D:\Tomcat7\temp\sqlite-3.7.2-sqlitejdbc.dll
    0x000000000f300000 - 0x000000000f311000     D:\Tomcat7\temp\jffi2022.tmp
    0x000000006d0a0000 - 0x000000006d24d000     D:\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\bin\awt.dll
    0x000007fef4bf0000 - 0x000007fef4c61000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
    0x000007fefb130000 - 0x000007fefb148000     C:\Windows\system32\DWMAPI.DLL
    0x000000006d2e0000 - 0x000000006d34b000     D:\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll
    0x0000000016e40000 - 0x0000000016e51000     D:\Tomcat7\temp\jffi2024.tmp
    0x000000006d290000 - 0x000000006d2b8000     D:\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\bin\dcpr.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dcatalina.home=d:\Tomcat7 -Dcatalina.base=d:\Tomcat7 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=d:\Tomcat7\endorsed -Djava.io.tmpdir=d:\Tomcat7\temp -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=d:\Tomcat7\conf\logging.properties -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:NewSize=3276M -XX:MaxNewSize=3276M -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8484 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -Xloggc:d:\Tomcat7\logs\GCLogs\gc.vgc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:HeapDumpPath=d:\Tomcat7\logs\Heap -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 exit -Xms3700m -Xmx8300m -Xss512k 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=D:\jdk1.6.0_10
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\jdk1.6.0_10\bin;D:\apache-ant-1.8.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\BCL Technologies\easyPDF 6;
USERNAME=OLYMPUS$
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 62 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows NT 6.1 Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 14 stepping 4, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 31456884k(1710500k free), swap 39843656k(9878240k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0-b15) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_10-b33), built on Sep 26 2008 00:53:37 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 8.0

time: Sun Feb 21 20:52:55 2016
elapsed time: 629358 seconds
```

Comment: Related [question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19812693/4290096) & [question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6448163/4290096)

Comment: Java 6 update 10 has had many bug fixed since it's release, I would try Java 6 update 45, if you know you can't upgrade to Java 8 update 74+

Comment: Yes, it's a JVM bug. JDK 6u10 is a way too old, you should definitely consider upgrading to JDK 8.